# Regex URL for Google Analytics - capture random string and folder

Tags: regex

I'm working on a GA Goal using a regex with my url that has randomly generated text/numbers. However I can't seem to get it tracking correctly.

URL: /booking/ramdomly-generated/

I want only the "booking" folder and the random text then I want to tell it to stop finding matches at that last trailing slash. This is because I have another url that keeps getting picked up (/booking/randomly-generated/checkout). I **do not** want the 'checkout' URLs to be counted towards this goal.

So far I have
.*/booking/.*/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `/booking/` the regex matches all characters until before the next `/`

```js
const regex = /\/booking\/[^\/]*/;

console.log( `/booking/bjcdbsc6s74rhf/checkout/`.match(regex)[0] );
console.log( `/booking/11a0fdebdbbfe73b529cf3bcd`.match(regex)[0] );
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately /\/booking\/.*\// doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: You can see in the snippet's console it does work. Maybe there is another problem in your code, can you share it? Otherwise I didn't understand correctly and it's not "/booking/randomly-generated/" the result you want.

Comment: Oh i see the issue, my URL has no slash on the end:/booking/11a0fdebdbbfe73b529cf3bcd but i don't want to track this one /booking/bjcdbsc6s74rhf/checkout

Comment: Thanks! Just tried this and when I re-verify it says - This Goal would have a 0% conversion rate based - even though i've had people access the page in the past few days. I'll give it ago setting it live anyway - thanks!

Comment: I went with this ^\/(booking)+\/[^\/]+[a-zA-Z0-9]$ and seems to work. Marked as solved, thanks!